# CakePhp: use plugin's template page

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using this plugin in my application:

[Audit plugin](https://github.com/rochamarcelo/cakephp-audit-log)

Which contains this template: `cakephp-audit-log/src/Template/Admin/Audits/index.ctp` which now is stored in app/plugins/AuditLog/src/Template/Admin/Audits/index.ctp . In the controller of the model that I want to use the plugin in order to audit any changes I have created this function in order to display that template:

```
public function audit(){
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('AuditLog.index');
    }
```

But I get this error when visiting in my browser the corresponding url:

> The layout file Layout\admin.index.ctp can not be found or does not exist.

How I can correctly use this view in my application?

Answer (score 0):

> cakephp-audit-log/src/Template/Admin/Audits/index.ctp

is not layout file, its just template for Admin perfixed Audits Controller index method!

In your case try :

```
// Plugin.Controller/Prefix/template
$this->render('AuditLog.Audits/Admin/index');
```

Comment: calling this: `$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('AuditLog.Admin.Audits.index');` it returns this error : `The layout file Layout\Admin.Audits.index.ctp can not be found or does not exist.`

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers.html#rendering-a-specific-template